# How to dial a number

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-number, phone-call

I am trying to dial a number like *123*0xxxxxxxxxx# . And the 0xxxxxxxxxx portion would be got from the user input through an edit text.my code is here

```
EditText et1;
String ET1;
String pnd,encode_zero;
Button call;

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.call);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call);

    ET1 = et1.getText().toString();
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                  pnd = Uri.encode("#");
          encode_zero = Uri.encode("0");
                  callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123*0" + ET1 + pnd));
                  startActivity(callIntent);

      }
  });
```

but when I run the app it ends with telling invalid number . that means I think the zero(0) is not considered. I have tried with this one too...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                  pnd = Uri.encode("#");
          encode_zero = Uri.encode("0");
                  callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123*" + encode_zero + ET1 + pnd));
                  startActivity(callIntent);

      }
```

but the result is all the same. 
Now what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: what android version are you testing on ?

Comment: You may need to log the user input to make sure it's correct.. also you may need to trim it (to remove unused spaces)

Comment: did you try changing ACTION_CALL to ACTION_DIAL ? maybe this will give you any hint

Answer (score 0):

This code opens the phone dialer with the number on it -

```
        String number = "*123*0123456#";
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(number)));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: bro , I've to call a number like *123*0123456#

Comment: then, try to escape character for tho stars. like this - \ *123\ *0123456\#

Comment: but I've to dial with the character also .

Comment: I have updated my answer. I tried it now. It works on my device. Have a try and tell if its useful.